# C# is an object[] as an inline parameter possible?

Tags: c#

If I have a method declared like this:

```
private void someFunction(object[] param1)
```

When I call this function do I have to declare the object array as a variable, or is there a quicker / shortcut way to just pass it inline to the function call.

I'm doing it like this:

```
Object[] myParam1 = new Object[2]
myParam1[0] = "blah";
myParam1[1] = "blah blah"; 
someFunction(myParam1);
```

In my real code, not this example, I'm calling COM from Marshal, and the code is getting messy each time I have to declare the arguments.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`someFunction(new [] { "blah", "blah blah", "more", "etc" });`

Comment: One note; the compiler must be able to infer the type of the array elements as something other than Object for an untyped array initializer to work. If you tried `someFunction(new [] { "blah", "blah blah", new MyObject });` it wouldn't work so well. However, `string[]` can be treated as `object[]` so this particular case will work.

Answer (score 9):

Well you could use array initializers that were introduced in C# 3.0:

```
someFunction(new object[] { "blah", "blah blah" });
```

and if you have your method declared like this:

```
private void someFunction(params object[] param1)
```

you could even write:

```
someFunction("blah", "blah blah");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array initializer:

```
someFunction(new object[]{"blah", "blah blah"});
```

You could also change the signature of someFunction to make param1 a params array:

```
private void someFunction(params object[] param1)
```

Then you wouldn't even need the initializer; just pass each "element" as its own parameter and the compiler will throw em in an array for you:

```
someFunction("blah", "Blah Blah");
```